# How can I import a part of a cocos2d project into another project

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

How can I import a part of a cocos2d project into another (non-cocos2d) project?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to the AttachTest in the cocos2d-ios project.
You can take a look to this [link](http://www.learningiphone.com/2010/09/post-a-day-5-uikit-cocos2d-view-based-cocos2d-application/) too.

Comment: this link doesn't help me please do you have something else for me ?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? Did you take a look to the AttachTest in the cocos2d-ios project ?

Comment: I don't understand what is the attach test. I found iton the cocos 2d project, and how can it help me

Comment: If you look at the code source of the AttachTest demo project, you could see how implement an EAGLView, wich is the cocos2d view, into an UIKit project (non-cocos2d project). Tell us what you want to do exactly because I don't understand at all where is you problem...

Comment: well I have created particle in a cocos2d view what I want is to put this code in my non cocos 2d project.Thus I have cocos2d particles in my non cocos2d project.DO you understand